# Update parse.com by backbone issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm updating by backbone parse.com but appear this error by parse.com:

code":206,"error":"Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError

model:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot:"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/",                           
   idAttribute: "objectId",
```

.....

collection:

```
    var Usercollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

 model:Person,
 url:'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/',
 idAttribute: "objectId",
 parse: function(data) {

    return data.results;
  }
```

code to update model:

```
  this.model.save({email:"ciao@lib.it"}, {
//wait:true,
success:function(model, response) {
    console.log('Successfully saved!');
},
error: function(model, error) {
    console.log(model.toJSON());
    console.log(error.responseText);
}
  });
```

Comment: Have you answered your own question? I'm stuck on the same exact thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the discussion in Parse.com](https://parse.com/questions/users-editing-other-users-in-javascript-sdk), user needs to login and can only modify its own data.

Comment: So can't i modify another user?

Comment: That is the answer from Parse:  "A User cannot be given permission to modify another User, not even through ACLs. What you would do is use the Master Key to modify objects at will. One way of doing this is through a Cloud Function."